# [typescript]I don't know how to inject genericity

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I want inject a genericity in my service, but I don't know how to do it, please help me, thinks.

```
import { Component } from "@nestjs/common";
import { InjectRepository } from "@nestjs/typeorm";
import { FindManyOptions, Repository } from "typeorm";

@Component()

export class BaseService<Model> {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(Model)
        private readonly modelRepository: Repository<Model>,
    ) { }

    public async find(options?: FindManyOptions<Model>): Promise<Model[]> {
        const result = await this.modelRepository.find(options);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tested yet ?

Comment: yes, throw error,Model is not defined

Comment: Where do you get that error? How have you tried to inject it into a component or other class?

Comment: yes,the InjectRepositiory is only apply the function

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is impossible due to TypeScript nature. Generic types are unavailable in JavaScript language, meaning, they are sorted out during transpilation. You cannot use them as a values/tokens.

Comment: I know the genericity can convert the class in the Java, the typescript can support the method or npm have the package about this ?

Comment: Unfortunately no. In Java generics are a part of the language.